# WAL Archive Backup and Restore

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, rhel7, pitr

In a postgresql, how to create WAL archieve ?
Step by step explanation is available for **Backup** and **Restore**
using **Linux** or **shell command**?

Enviroment :
OS : LINUX RHEL 7.4
DB : Postgresql 9.2

is there any options without stopping postgresql complete backup as well as restore ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it is described https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/continuous-archiving.html

with examples for unix like system.

you dont have to stop postgres to take backup, neither base backup, nor wals

Comment: For restore need to stop server.when server stop and any one try to access then will show error right ?

Comment: if you restore in same server, just specify different directory. you cant recover existing cluster back in time - only spin up a copy and recover it till some point